# Converting data type of a column from object to numeric

Tags: pandas

i tried to convert dtype from object to numeric using pd.to_numeric(df.col,errors='coerce')it ran well,but in the next cell when i did df.col the dtype is showing object.what is the problem here.

pd.to_numeric(df.col,errors='coerce')

Answer (score 1):

I think you need reassign back column `col`:

```
df.col = pd.to_numeric(df.col,errors='coerce')
```